# selecting a good upper bound on quadratic form in presence of unknown PD matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, quadratic-forms

I have a cost function that is 
\begin{equation}
J=\text{Trace} [\ (\ I-LC)\ KQK^T(\ I-LC)\ ^T ]\  
\end{equation}

where $Q$ is a unknown positive definite matrix, $K$ and $C$ are full rank $n\times n$ and $m\times n$ matrices, respectively. Objective is to find $L$ such that minimizes $J$.
Because $Q$ is unknown, I can't use it in minimization, so I tried to minimize upper bound of $J$. We can consider two upper bounds
\begin{equation}
J\leq \lambda_{max}(Q) \text{Trace} [\ (\ I-L_1C)\ KK^T(\ I-L_1C)\ ^T ]\ 
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
J\leq \lambda_{max}(KQK^T) \text{Trace} [\ (\ I-L_2C)\ (\ I-L_2C)\ ^T ]\ 
\end{equation}
$\lambda_{max}(Q)$ and $\lambda_{max}(KQK^T)$ are unknown, but non-negative, so the only way is to minimizing Trace parts. $L_1$ and $L_2$ that minimize those are
\begin{equation}
L_1=KK^TC^T(\ CKK^TC^T)\ ^{-1}
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
L_2=C^T(\ CC^T)\ ^{-1}
\end{equation}

Now it makes sense that 
\begin{equation}
\lambda_{max}(Q) \text{Trace} [\ (\ I-L_1C)\ KK^T(\ I-L_1C)\ ^T ]\   \leq \lambda_{max}(KQK^T) \text{Trace} [\ (\ I-L_2C)\ (\ I-L_2C)\ ^T ]\ 
\end{equation}
but I can't prove this.

what do you think?

Thanks

---

P.S: A constraint for $Q$ that can be considered is
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
Q_{ii}&>|Q_{ij}|\qquad&\text{for}\qquad i\not= j\\
Q_{ii}&=Q_{jj}\qquad&\text{for}\qquad i\not= j
\end{split}
\end{equation}
and $n\gg m$, $C=[\ I_m\quad 0]\ $

Comment: What do you mean, $Q$ is unknown? It is another degree of freedom in the optimization? Or you need to minimize something like the supremum of $J$ over all possible $Q$?

Comment: second one, I need to minimize supremum of $J$ over all symmetric positive definite $Q$.

Comment: Is there no constraint on $Q$ except being SPD? Otherwise, I can't see why such an optimization problem would have a solution except in the very special case that you can zero-out $I-LC$.

Comment: Edited question.